# Abbyy Flexicapture Data Extraction

Tags: extract, ocr, abbyy

I am new in the Abbyy world. I use Abbyy FlexiLayout Studio 12. I have a pdf file contains the following reports.

I want to extract the following fields:

1: Kredi Kartları . It is at the same position everytime.

2: Açık. It canbe "Açık" or "Kapalı"

3: There are list of months in Turkish. Also there is a ✓ or X character. It is image not text. I want to get the corresponding character for each month.

I added search element whose type is field label for 1 and 2. But I could not extract the 3. since it contains image.

Also as you see in the image, there are 3 different report in the same page. I want to extract 3 of them for this case

[image]